# Can I remove the Liferay 7 default "Global" and "Liferay" sites?

Tags: liferay-7

I have a fresh version of Liferay 7 installed and want to create a custom site and not use the default ones. There are 2 default sites already created by Liferay - Liferay & Gobal:

[image]

I was wondering how can I remove them if I am not going to work with them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete the default site of your Liferay installation but you can change its URL prefix and the site title.

- You can change the URL entering inside the site -> Settings -> Friendly URL
- The default site title is taken from the instance title, so you can change both from: Control Panel -> Configuration -> Instance Settings -> Instance Configuration -> General -> Name

Answer (score 0):

After reading some articles, I came down to the conclusion that default sites can not be deleted.